# What should I do for creating " new line through enter key” and then display paragraph when selecting “see what can u wrote”

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create paragraph box. but unable to place logic for "enter" (when user <kbd>press</kbd> enter it should immediately goes to new line.
This is the code but it writes in the line, i want the string to be placed in new line:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function write(){
    var Input = document.getElementById('Input').value;
    document.getElementById('writeText').innerHTML = Input;
}
</script>
<p>You wrote: <span id='writeText'></span> </p> 

<input type='text' id='Input' value='Write here' />
<input type='button' onclick='write()' value='See what you wrote'/>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: i am trying to create paragraph box. but unable to place logic for  "enter" (when user press enter it shd immediately goes to new line).

Comment: for example this code doing this when i write. "I am boy hajhan sadsaadsadas ". now i want when i press entr key it should go in new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiline text fields require a `<textarea>` element instead of a `<input type="text">` element. There is no "logic for enter", this has nothing to do with JavaScript, you just need to use the correct element.

Comment: so i shd write <textarea type='text id='input' value='write here'/>.  Is that way?.

Comment: No, you should write `<textarea id="Input">Write Here</textarea>`. There's lots of information on this... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: am also saving in variable. so that i shd display every time.

Comment: It's "should". "shd" isn't a word. Persisting the data across requests is a completely different question.